# Authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) for OsCommerce

Tags: module, authorize.net, add-on, oscommerce, recurring-billing

I have searched the web for authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) in osCommerce, but I failed to find module/addon and haven't found any tips for this. Anybody know about how to implement or create a module for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the reason you will not find that, is that oscommerce does not provide a way to price recurring products. They are only one time purchases.

I would recommend looking for a solution that handles recurring billing.